# A windows form application framework using python

Tags: python, designer

Hey I'm looking for a way to develop a windows form application like the one in visual studio, that using c# and has a visual designer option but that using python instead.
I know that I can use tkinter to create a WFA but I really need that designer option.
Any suggestions?

--edit--

Thanks for your replies but does PyQt work with Visual Studio 2019 or do I have to use the Qt designer?

Comment: PyQt5 and PyQt5 Designer

Comment: there are plenty of youtube videos to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `PyQt5-tools`:

1. pip install it : `pip install PyQt5-tools`
2. Then navigate to `Lib/site-packages/pyqt5_tools` open the designer, design what you have in mind and save it.
3. Now run Scripts/pyuic5 like this :

```
    scripts/pyuic5 -x path to your sth.ui -o your_design.py
```

(where `sth.ui` is the file saved in PyQt designer. The command in step 3 converts the `sth.ui` file to a .py file.)
(you need to be in the root of your python distribution)
there you have your window, etc in python and now you can write the logic for it.

You may also find [this video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLUZjzUfQbk) useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PyQT. It has a visual Builder named QT Designer and you can generate a python file from it.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 and PyQt5 Designer are what you need.
I made one project https://github.com/XtremeGood/Mailer .

But that's not enough. To make it an executable you will need to know how to use pyinstaller and then use NSIS scripting or https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NSIS_Quick_Setup_Script_Generator to package it to create a windows executable file.